# cant download http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/ios_sdk_4.2__final/xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final.dmg

Tags: ios-4.2

I cant download "http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/ios_sdk_4.2__final/xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final.dmg". the link returns "Mounting Failed" on my macbook. what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did your session expire? When I go to that URL it requires me to log in.

Comment: It is not related to the session, it only says so 'cos I copied from within my profile. Actually this is the main ios sdk 4.2 link on developer.apple.com. I don't know why it always fails to mount on my macbook.

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to login, download the file, THEN mount it, instead of mounting the URL directly?

Comment: Yes I do login before any attempt. The same thing happened to me when I wanted to install the SDK4.1. I only succeeded by downloading from a different website storage altogether.

Comment: it expires due to slow network, and was continually cutting off. I got a better network & it downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

"Mounting Failed" means that you can't mount the file. Maybe it's broken. Try to download it again.

And when I open the link it says: Session expired. Maybe you need to login and try downloading again.

Comment: It is not related to the session, it only says so 'cos I copied from within my profile. Actually this is the main ios sdk 4.2 link on developer.apple.com. I don't know why it always fails to mount on my macbook.